# Done function never called after $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm a bit new to all this (including Javascript callbacks and ES6). I'm using NodeJS + Express + MongoDB.

I'm calling an Ajax function to update an item and the success Ajax call is never done.

Here is my Ajax call (called from React)

```
editBug : function(bug){

    console.log('about to edit bug with these values',bug);
    $.ajax({
        url:'/api/bugs',
        method: 'PUT',
        data:bug
    })
    .done((jqxhr) => {
        console.log('succcess while editing the bug');
        this.setState({successVisible : true});
    })
    .fail((jqxhr) => {
        console.log('error : ' + jqxhr);
    })  
},
```

Here is my API function:

```
app.put('/api/bugs',function(req,res){

    //console.log('req',req);
    console.log('query string : ',req.query);
    console.log('query params : ',req.params);
    console.log('query body: ',req.body);
    let id = new ObjectID(req.body._id);
    req.body._id = new ObjectID(req.body._id);

    db.collection('bugs').replaceOne(
        {_id:id},
        req.body,
        function(err,result){
            assert.equal(err,null);
            console.log('Successfull replace!');
            res.status(200);
        }
    );
});
```

The `Successfull replace!` log is correctly shown on the server side.
The `about to edit bug with these values` is correctly shown on the front side. But the `succcess while editing the bug` log is not shown on front end and it seems `.done` call is never executed.

Comment: You don't mention if the `fail()` is or is not called.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?  Promises are added on jquery 1.6

Comment: @freedomn-m `fail()` is not called.

Comment: @guyfawkes jquery 3.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending any response back to the browser on node side. Try the following snippet and you should be good to go

Also, I'd like to point out that you should handle the errors. While updating the `bugs` if something goes wrong, the best practice would be to inform the browser with the 500 status code indicating that the intended action failed. I've added this aspect in the snipped below

```
app.put('/api/bugs', function(req, res) {

  //console.log('req',req);
  console.log('query string : ', req.query);
  console.log('query params : ', req.params);
  console.log('query body: ', req.body);
  let id = new ObjectID(req.body._id);
  req.body._id = new ObjectID(req.body._id);

  db.collection('bugs').replaceOne({
      _id: id
    },
    req.body,
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Failed replace');
        res.status(500).end(); // <- We set the response status code and end the request
      } else {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log('Successfull replace!');
        res.status(200).end(); // <- We set the response status code and end the request
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I picked your answer as the correct one since it is more detailed than the other one (also true). Thanks a lot for your quick help! And for the bit about handling the errors. Actually I'm following a tutorial that's why I'm only doing the 'quick' stuff. But you're totally right

Answer (score 3):

Don't you need to end your response object on the Node.js side? 
Try adding `res.end();` or any kind of response to your response object.

Also, you can use chrome's (or any other browser's) network tab to actually see how your AJAX requests end up, to see if they hang or finish.

Comment: Thanks. res.end() does work! I didn't think about that because before I was using res.json(doc) and it seemed to do everything (close the stream as well).